# "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created" despite "initializeApp()" has been called (Flutter, Firebase)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have the following workpiece of a starting widget:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'apps/auth_app.dart';
import 'apps/main_app.dart';

class StartingWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartingWidget({super.key});

  void _initFirebase() async {
    //WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

  void _addAuthStatusListener() {
    try {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        if (user != null) {
          //runApp(const MainApp());
        } else {
          //runApp(const AuthApp());
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _initFirebase();
    _addAuthStatusListener();
    return const Scaffold(
      body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
}
```

When I start it on an Android emulator, I get the "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created" error at line

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
```

despite `Firebase.initializeApp()` was called before. Uncommenting

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple:

You have not waited for your `_initFirebase()` to complete, before you call `_addAuthStatusListener()`, which uses the Firebase app!

You also can't wait inside your build method (it has to render immediately and therefore can't be async), so I suggest you call `_initFirebase()` from inside `_addAuthStatusListener()` instead:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//    _initFirebase();  // <- Remove this here!
    _addAuthStatusListener();
    return const Scaffold(
      body: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  }
```

...

```
  void _addAuthStatusListener() async {  // Make async!
    await _initFirebase();  // <- Add _initFirebase() here, with "await"!
    try {
      FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
        if (user != null) {
          //runApp(const MainApp());
        } else {
          //runApp(const AuthApp());
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

That should do it!

**Explanation** 
What you have to understand about async functions is that calling them without the `await` keyword only STARTS them. Then, the reader continues, without waiting for them to finish. Meanwhile, the async function also continues with its own stuff, in parallell with the main reader, until it's done.

And so, in your case above, you started the `_initFirebase()`, and inside there, a reader sat down and waited for `Firebase.initializeApp()` to complete. But while that was going on, the main reader continued to the next line in the `build()` method, which was `_addAuthStatusListener()`. And this function had plenty of time to make it to where it would have needed your completely initialized Firebase app (the line where you got the error), before said initialization had a chance to complete.

Later on, the `Firebase.initializeApp()` command would have completed, soon after which the entire `_initFirebase()` function would have completed, but by then, your app had already crashed.

Adding "await" before `_initFirebase()` makes sure, however, that the reader can't continue to the next line until this function has completed, even though it is async.